# displaying data to select option and filtering by ASC / DESC in react js?

Tags: reactjs

In my inertia project. I have an array of Assign ID from user table like :

```
["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]`
```

I intend to make it filter data as ASC/DESC..

in my :

> Controller.php

```
public function index()
    {
        $query = Project::query();

        $sortField = request("sort_field", 'created_at');
        $sortDirection = request("sort_direction", "desc");

        if (request("assign_user_id")) {
            $query->where("assign_user_id", request("assign_user_id"));
        }
        $project = $query->orderBy($sortField, $sortDirection)
            ->paginate(10)
            ->onEachSide(1);

        return inertia("Project/Index", [
            "projects" => ProjectResource::collection($tasks),
            'queryParams' => request()->query() ?: null,
        ]);
    }
```

then in the my :

> project.jsx

```
export default function Project({
  projects,
  queryParams = null,
}) {

  queryParams = queryParams || {};
  const searchFieldChanged = (name, value) => {
    if (value) {
      queryParams[name] = value;
    } else {
      delete queryParams[name];
    }

    router.get(route("project.index"), queryParams);
  };
  
  const userId = project.data.map((val) => val.assignUser.id);
  const uniqueId = Array.from(new Set(userId));
  
  const sortChanged = (name) => {
    if (name === queryParams.sort_field) {
      if (queryParams.sort_direction === "asc") {
        queryParams.sort_direction = "desc";
      } else {
        queryParams.sort_direction = "asc";
      }
    } else {
      queryParams.sort_field = name;
      queryParams.sort_direction = "asc";
    }
    router.get(route("project.index"), queryParams);
  };
  
  return (
    <>
    <th>
    <SelectInput
      defaultValue={queryParams.id}
      onChange={(e) =>
        searchFieldChanged("assign_user_id", e.target.value)
      }
    >
      <option value="">Select User</option>
      {uniqueId.map((opt) => (
        <option value={opt}>{opt}</option>
      ))}
    </SelectInput>
  </th>
    </>
}
```

I have a problem when I select one of the IDs, it doesn't return to the default (or) selected value inside the Select Option Column.. And the Select Option Column data disappears

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.